# qt:RCC parse error while executing step "Make"

Tags: c++, qt

What I want to do now is simply show my .qrc picture to my scene, but something keep going wrong with my program. I've checked my path and it should be fine.
thanks in advance for the great help!

my picture is placed in a folder called "img" under my project.(img folder was newed by right clicking main.cpp and choose "show containing folder")

it shows **[qrc_myresources.cpp] Error 1** as i run it, which quite confuse me. I've searched for stack overflow but didn't find the solution.

compile output:

> 00:30:13: Running steps for project shoot...
>       00:30:13: Configuration unchanged, skipping qmake step.
>       00:30:13: Starting: "/usr/bin/make" 
>       /home/pd2vm/Qt5.9.2/5.9.2/gcc_64/bin/rcc -name myresources ../shoot/myresources.qrc -o qrc_myresources.cpp
>       RCC Parse Error: '../shoot/myresources.qrc' Line: 10 Column: 6 [expected  tag]
>       Makefile:597: recipe for target 'qrc_myresources.cpp' failed
>       make: *** [qrc_myresources.cpp] Error 1
>       00:30:13: The process "/usr/bin/make" exited with code 2.
>       Error while building/deploying project shoot (kit: Desktop Qt 5.9.2 GCC 64bit)
>       When executing step "Make"
>       00:30:13: Elapsed time: 00:00.

mainwindow.h

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QGraphicsScene>
#include <QGraphicsPixmapItem>
#include <QTimer>
#include <QKeyEvent>

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

public slots:
virtual void keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent *e);

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
    QGraphicsScene *scene;

    QGraphicsPixmapItem *player;
    QTimer *timer;


};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

mainwindow.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow),
    timer(new QTimer)

{
    QGraphicsScene * scene = new QGraphicsScene(0,0,1200,880);
    ui->setupUi(this);
    ui->graphicsView->setScene(scene);

    //player
    player = new QGraphicsPixmapItem(QPixmap(":/img/whitedog.png"));
    scene->addItem(player);
    player->setPos(600, 880);
    timer->start(10);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

myresources.qrc

```
<RCC>
<qresource prefix="/">
        <file>img/whitedog.png</file>
    </qresource>
<RCC/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know much about Qt but that looks like xml and so shouldn't the slash go before the closing tag name. Like this:

```
<RCC>
...
</RCC>
```

Sorry if that's not the solution. Just the first thing I noticed.